# Modify XML attribute PHP DOM

Tags: php, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this.

```
<collections id="my collections">
 <category id="my category">
   <record id="my record">
     <title>Some Info</title>
   </record>
 </category>
</collections>
```

I am looking for away to replace any attribute in the above XML file with a new attribute,Using PHP DOM and Xpath.
Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do exactly, but the general idea is :

- You must instanciate [**`DOMDocument`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)
- and load your XML strings with it : [**`DOMDocument::loadXML`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php)
- Then, you must instanciate [**`DOMXpath`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php) on that document
- And use it to query the document : [**`DOMXPath::query`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)
- One you have found the node that interests you, you can manipulate it

  - for example, you can set the value of an attribute : [**`DOMElement::setAttribute`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php)

Here, for example, you could use some thing like this :

```
$str = <<<XML
    <collections id="My Collections">
     <category id="my category">
       <record id="my record">
         <title>Some Info</title>
       </record>
     </category>
    </collections>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($str);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$elements = $xpath->query('//record[@id="my record"]');
if ($elements->length >= 1) {
    $element = $elements->item(0);
    $element->setAttribute('id', "glop !");
}
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()) . '</pre>';
```

This will replace the `id` attribute `my record`, on the node that's identified by it, by "`glop !`", and you'd get the following XML as output :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<collections id="My Collections">
     <category id="my category">
       <record id="glop !">
         <title>Some Info</title>
       </record>
     </category>
    </collections>
```

Answer (score 1):

Suposing id='my record' is unique in the xml. The hard work is only in the xpath expression.

```
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->load('test.xml');
    $xp = new DomXPath($dom);
    $res = $xp->query("//*[@id = 'my record']");
    $res->item(0)->setAttribute('id','2');
    $dom->save('test.xml');
```