# fetch details from xml tag

Tags: php, xml

Given the following XML file:

```
<FlightHistoryGetRecordsResponse>
−
    <FlightHistory
            DepartureAirportTimeZoneOffset="2" ArrivalAirportTimeZoneOffset="1"
            ActualAirTime="101" ActualAircraftType="319"
            ActualBlockTime="124" ActualGateArrivalDate="2010-07-10T11:58:00.000"
            ActualGateDepartureDate="2010-07-10T10:54:00.000"
            ActualRunwayArrivalDate="2010-07-10T11:52:00.000"
            ActualRunwayDepartureDate="2010-07-10T11:11:00.000"
            ArrivalDate="2010-07-10T12:05:00.000" ArrivalTerminal="5"
            CreatorCode="O" DepartureDate="2010-07-10T11:05:00.000" DepartureTerminal=""
            EstimatedGateArrivalDate="2010-07-10T11:48:00.000"
            EstimatedGateDepartureDate="2010-07-10T11:05:00.000"
            FlightHistoryId="197151356" FlightNumber="991"
            PublishedArrivalDate="2010-07-10T12:05:00.000"
            PublishedDepartureDate="2010-07-10T11:05:00.000" ScheduledAircraftType="319"
            ScheduledBlockTime="120" ScheduledGateArrivalDate="2010-07-10T12:05:00.000"
            ScheduledGateDepartureDate="2010-07-10T11:05:00.000"
            Status="Landed" StatusCode="L">
        <Airline AirlineCode="BA" IATACode="BA" ICAOCode="BAW" Name="British Airways"/>
        <Origin AirportCode="TXL" IATACode="TXL" ICAOCode="EDDT" Name="Tegel Airport"/>
        <Destination AirportCode="LHR" IATACode="LHR" ICAOCode="EGLL" Name="Heathrow Airport"/>
    </FlightHistory>
</FlightHistoryGetRecordsResponse>
```

I want to fetch the below details from that XML TAG using PHP:

1. ArrivalTerminal
2. Status
3. StatusCode
4. ScheduledGateArrivalDate
5. ActualGateArrivalDate

How do I fetch the above details?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify XML attribute PHP DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723816/modify-xml-attribute-php-dom) - it's not exactly the same but covers the same grounds. You will also find an answer to [how to fetch attributes from XML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+fetch+attributes+from+XML+php) when doing a search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

$arrivalTerminal = (string)$xmlObj->FlightHistory['ArrivalTerminal'];
$status = (string)$xmlObj->FlightHistory['Status'];
$statusCode = (string)$xmlObj->FlightHistory['StatusCode'];
$scheduledGateArrivalDate = (string)$xmlObj->FlightHistory['ScheduledGateArrivalDate'];
$actualGateArrivalDate = (string)$xmlObj->FlightHistory['ActualGateArrivalDate'];
```