# modifying xml document using php

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, simplexml

i have an xml file "Machine.xml"  it contains:

```
<Parameter name="host" value="localhost"/>
<Parameter name="port" value="5900"/>
```

i would like to change both parameters values using a php script... how can i do that?
i mean i want the script to change host's value for example to : value="7.3.4.5" and
port value to: value="3124" AND then save the xml file again with these changes.

i tried several ways, but none worked

thx a lot:)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modify XML attribute PHP DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723816/modify-xml-attribute-php-dom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked in many variations before. Search through SO to find out how to do it with DOM and the following XPath

```
//Parameter[@name="host"]/@value
```

and

```
//Parameter[@name="port"]/@value
```

Comment: man, I think this is the second time today you have beaten me to the punch while typing...

Comment: no problems.  I'm just new and trying to give back because SO has helped me learn so much.