# how to edit html in php

Tags: php

I have a string somethink like

```
   <p><img alt="twerk team" class="pyro-image" src="http://localhost/test/files/thumb/8/595" style="float: none;" /></p>
```

and what i want to add new string in that

```
<p><img alt="twerk team" class="pyro-image" src="http://localhost/test/files/thumb/8/595/test_image.jpg" style="float: none;" /></p>
```

i have tried DOMDocument and Simple HTML parser but not able to do the same. please have a look.

Comment: We cant' have a look. You forgot to post the code ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723816/modify-xml-attribute-php-dom ? Anyway, for a very narrow case like this I think you can `preg_replace`it out without letting any children be melt in acid.

Comment: can you explain your question more....

Comment: assign `id="anything"` attribute to `<img>`. And change `attr` using JScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will append `/test_image.jpg` to the `src` of each image element with a class of `pyro-image`.

**[Demo](http://codepad.org/0CexzyGr)**

```
$html = '<p><img alt="twerk team" class="pyro-image" src="http://localhost/test/files/thumb/8/595" style="float: none;" /></p>';

$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($html);

$xp = new DomXPath($d);
$class = 'pyro-image';
$nodes = $xp->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

foreach($nodes as $n)
{
    $n->setAttribute('src', (string)$n->getAttribute('src') . '/test_image.jpg');
    echo $d->saveXML($n->parentNode);

    // note - can use saveHTML() instead but only from PHP 5.3.6
}
```

**Outputs**

```
<p><img alt="twerk team" class="pyro-image" src="http://localhost/test/files/thumb/8/595/test_image.jpg" style="float: none;"/></p>
```

Comment: I want only <p><img alt="twerk team" class="pyro-image" src="http://localhost/test/files/thumb/8/595/test_image.jpg" style="float: none;"></p>      ... is that possible with this

Comment: @Pramod I've updated the code - it now just outputs what you want